# Activity result not being remembered?

Tags: android

I have the following scenario (note that activity **A** has `launchMode="singleTop"`):

1. Activity **A** calls `startActivityForResult()` on activity **B**;
2. Activity **B** calls `startActivity()` on **C**, after which `setResult(RESULT_OK)` and `finish()`; at this point, `onActivityResult()` in **A** is **NOT** called.
3. Activity **C** calls `startActivity()` on **A** using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `finish()`;

This is where my problem occurs. At this point, **A**'s `onActivityResult()` is called with the right `requestCode`, but something else than `RESULT_OK` as the `resultCode`. I was expecting it to receive `RESULT_OK` because I have set it in **B** (which was started for result).

Why am I getting something other than `RESULT_OK`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this doc:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

> If set, and the activity being launched
>   is already running in the current
>   task, then instead of launching a new
>   instance of that activity, all of the
>   other activities on top of it will be
>   closed and this Intent will be
>   delivered to the (now on top) old
>   activity as a new Intent.

Passing clear top flag will finish all activities in the stack. So what you'll get in `onActivityResult` is probably a "notification" that the activity for which you want the result was canceled. (aka RESULT_CANCELED = 0x00)

**UPDATE**

When I use `startActivityForResult`, after setting the result, I always finish my activity and let the caller come to action.

You are doing something less common: you set the result, finish your activity **but** you also start another one. I don't know is the expected behavior in this situation. Can't you change the interaction between the activities?

You could try to call `finish()` first and then start the new activity (do this in activities B and C). Anyway, I also don't know what should happen when you do this. I recommend you the first approach (changing the interaction so you don't return a result and create a new activity at the same time).

Perhaps you could chain two `startActivityForResult` or your activity B could send a new intent to A instead of returning its result?

Comment: All the other activities (in my case, **B**) have already finished and `setResult(RESULT_OK);`. It shouldn't be overwriting my result.

Comment: I ultimately made my **C** activity directly start **A** and ditched the entire result-based logic. I thought about chaining `startActivityForResult()` calls, but it's not possible in my situation since **C** is a more generic activity which is reused in other scenarios as well.

Comment: One last remark: if you call ``setResult`` and ``finish`` when that activity wasn't started via ``startActivityForResult``, nothing happens (no ``onActivityResult`` is called) so I guess you could reuse activity C without any problem.

Comment: if the request code is set to -1, startActivityForResult() is equivalent to startActivity()