# Android activity results not being checked

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-bluetooth

I have an app that goes `LoginActivity` -> `MainActivity`. Main activity is started like this as I dont want `LoginActivity` to be added to the stack:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Upon starting `MainActivity`, in `onResume` I check to see if Bluetooth is enabled. If not, ask the user if they want to enable it (this takes place in a helper class `btHelper`):

```
public void enableBT(){
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        mainActivity.startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
}
```

So here, I need to check what the user chooses. If they pick yes then I will enable BT and register a broadcast receiver. If they choose no, I want to finish `MainActivity` and go back to `LoginActivity`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == btHelper.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //Register broadcast receiver once BT is enabled
                btHelper.registerBroadcastReceiver();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                finishAffinity();
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run the app, if the user chooses Yes then everything works fine. If they choose No, then again, everything works fine and they're taken the the Login screen. However, when they log in again, of course the dialog will come up asking if they want to enable BT, but if they choose No this second time around then they are not taken to Login - the dialog simply redisplays

I've seen this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264135/activity-result-not-being-remembered) but it doesn't seem applicable as I am not programmatically setting any results. For some reason the users choice of No/Deny only gets checked correctly the first time around but not the second

Given that when I click No/Deny the dialog shows itself again, I'm thinking that maybe `onResume()` is being called again thus calling `enableBT()`? I'm not sure whether the problem is something like that or the way I'm handling transition between activities

EDIT:

I've narrows the problem down a bit. I added a line to log out the `resultCode` value whenever `onActivityResult` gets called. During the first run, `resultCode` gets displayed correctly, but on second run after restarting `MainActivity` no code is ever logged. With some more testing, it seems that on second run whenever I hit No/Deny, `enableBT`/`onResume` is being called instead of first checking the result code to determine what it should do - its just automatically restarting the activity/fragment. Does this mean `onActivityResult` isn't getting called or that no result code is present?

EDIT2: full code added below...

LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Check if this is a fresh app launch, or a launcher click after app minimize
        if (!isTaskRoot()
                && getIntent().hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
                && getIntent().getAction() != null
                && getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {

            finish();
            return;
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        coordinatorLayoutView = findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout_login);

        //get views for textboxes and buttons

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //perform some password checking, then login

                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Get fragment manager
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        //Start the initial fragment
        connectFragment = new ConnectFragment();
        addFragment(connectFragment, false);

        //Set navigation drawer/menu here

        //Create bluetooth helper
        btHelper = BTHelper.getInstance(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        //Check and enable bluetooth
        if (btHelper.getBTAdapter() == null) {
            //Show alert here saying bluetooth is required, when OK is pressed, invoke `quitToLogin()`
        } else {
            //If bluetooth is not enabled, ask to enable it
            btHelper.enableBT();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy called");
        super.onDestroy();
        btHelper.unregisterBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, Boolean addToBackStack) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            //Check getFragments() == null to prevent the initial blank
            //fragment (before 'Connect' fragment is displayed) from being added to the backstack
            if (fragmentManager.getFragments() == null || !addToBackStack) {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                        .commit();
            } else {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Result code: " + Integer.toString(resultCode));

        if (requestCode == btHelper.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //Register broadcast receiver once BT is enabled
                btHelper.registerBroadcastReceiver();
            } else {
                quitToLogin();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == btHelper.REQUEST_ENABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
            if (resultCode == 60) { //result code is discoverable time set in helper
                //Start discovery
                btHelper.startDiscovery();
            } else {
                //do other things
            }
        }
    }

    public void quitToLogin(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finishAffinity();
    }
}
```

BTHelper:

```
public class BTHelper {
    public static final String TAG = "BTHelper";

    private static BTHelper sInstance;
    Activity mainActivity;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 0;
    final int REQUEST_ENABLE_DISCOVERABLE = 1;

    //Flags
    Boolean discoveryStarted;
    Boolean broadcastReceiverEnabled;

    public static synchronized BTHelper getInstance(Activity activity) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new BTHelper(activity);
            Log.d(TAG, "New BTHelper created");
        }

        return sInstance;
    }

    private BTHelper(Activity activity) {
        this.mainActivity = activity;
        this.mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        this.discoveryStarted = false;
        this.broadcastReceiverEnabled = false;
    }

    public BluetoothAdapter getBTAdapter(){
        return this.mBluetoothAdapter;
    }

    public void enableBT(){
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "enableBT is called");
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            mainActivity.startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }

    public void registerBroadcastReceiver(){
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        mainActivity.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        this.broadcastReceiverEnabled = true;
    }

    public void unregisterBroadcastReceiver(){
        if(this.broadcastReceiverEnabled){
            mainActivity.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        }
        this.broadcastReceiverEnabled = false;
    }

    public boolean checkBondedDevices(){
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            // Loop through paired devices to check for match
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                //conditions here to find a specific device and connect to it    
                return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void enableDiscoverable(){
        //Enable discoverability
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 60);
        mainActivity.startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_DISCOVERABLE);
    }

    public void startDiscovery(){
        //Start discovering devices
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting discovery...");
        this.discoveryStarted = true;
        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for bluetooth ACTION_FOUND
    public final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                //Check for matching device
                if(check device name/MAC address of specific device){

                    //Stop discovery
                    discoveryStarted = false;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

                    //Connect to device here
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: what happens if you call finish() instead of finishAffinity() ?

Comment: Same thing - No/Deny just causes `enableBT` to be called again without first checking the result code (or even entering `onActivityResult` at all)

Comment: and how do you assign this mainActivity variable ?

Comment: Ive added the code for each class to the question. I pass a reference to the activity to the helper, then store that in the helper class object as `mainActivity`

Comment: So second time your BTHelper is already instantiated !!!! it will not set the reference to the new main activity !!! Try setting it with a setter method rather than on the singleton parameter.

Comment: set the singleton getInstance() parmeterless. so your code will be like btHelper = BTHelper.getInstane(); btHelper.setActivity(this);

Comment: oh wow that worked, thanks. Happy to accept that if you post as an answer. Also, I'm curious to know why that fixes it?

Comment: posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `BTHelper` class is a `Singleton`, which means only one instance is available during application runtime.

So in your `getInstance()` method you are passing the `Activity` to it. First time it gets initialized with the activity. The activity finishes and after logging in the **"new"** MainActivity starts. It calls `BTHelper.getInstance(this)` again. This time it sees that `sInstance` is not null (as `sInstance` is static and was set previously) , so its returning the `sInstance` which held the previous reference to the previous main activity which is now destroyed probably. Actually its very bad practice to have a permitarized `getInstance` in `Singleton` classes. You have one copy of `BTHelper`, but you want to use it with different instances of main activity. So its better to have a field activity and set each time you want to use `BTHelper` like this:

```
btHelper = BTHelper.getInstance();
btHelper.setCallingActivity(this);
```

You should also read about [Singleton Design Pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html) (if thats required ;) )